# Sum values if values of related cells are in range

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a Calc spreadsheet as follows:

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E
--------------------------------
1 |  0  |  4  |  5  |  0  |
2 |  5  |  6  |  9  |  8  |
3 |  4  |  9  |     |     |
4 |  9  |  3  |     |     |
```

I want to get in E the sum of elements in B whose corresponding cell in A has a value contained in C or D. For example, E1 should be 10 (i.e. B1+B2) since both A1 and A2 values are present in C1:D1. Similarly, E2 should be 3 (i.e. B4) since only A4 has a value in C2:D2.
How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the following formula in E1 and fill down to E4 to produce `10` and `3`.

```
=IF(C1<>"";SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A$4=C1)+(A$1:A$4=D1);B$1:B$4);"")
```

This works by getting an array of one value for each row that is true or false depending on whether each value in A exists in C or D of that row. If false, then it multiplies whatever is in that row by 0, effectively disposing of that row. If true, then the value in B is multiplied by 1. All non-zero results are added up.

Originally I tried using `OR`, but `+` is required instead because `OR` can only handle one row at a time.

The `C1` check avoids trying to calculate the rows where C is empty.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works (and I would never have figured it out!).